# What network configuration manager am I using?

Tags: networking, systemd

I recently upgraded 14.04 to 16.04, which includes a transition from Upstart to `systemd`, and I can't figure out what `systemd` is doing with my network.

`NetworkManager`, `systemd-networkd`, and `systemd-resolved` are all inactive:

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
$ systemctl status systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor pre
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
$ systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor pre
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d
           └─resolvconf.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
```

No trace of either `NetworkManager` or `systemd-networkd` are in my `journalctl` from the last boot:

```
$ journalctl -u NetworkManager
-- No entries --
$ journalctl -u systemd-networkd
-- No entries --
```

Nevertheless, the network is fine.  The server is connecting to the DB server and its webapps are internet-accessible as normal.  How do I determine what network configuration manager I'm using?  I have to be using one, right?

**Edit** Here are the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#iface eth0 inet static
#   address x.x.x.x
#   netmask x.x.x.x
#   network x.x.x.x
#   broadcast x.x.x.x
#   gateway x.x.x.x
#   # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
#   dns-nameservers x.x.x.x y.y.y.y
#   dns-search x.x.x.x y.y.y.y
```

Comment: It may be directly configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`. It is normal for a server.

Comment: @Pilot6 Is `/etc/network/interfaces` associated with a unit or service?  How will it appear in `journalctl` during boot?

Comment: `ifupdown.service`

Comment: @Pilot6 Like `NetworkManager`, `ifupdown.service` is also "not-found" and "inactive," and it does not appear in `journalctl`.  I need to find out what network configuration manager is currently active, not how to configure it.

Comment: This is a good question! Maybe you are still using upstart.

Comment: @Pilot6 Referring to the highest-voted answer [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196166/how-to-find-out-if-a-system-uses-sysv-upstart-or-systemd-initsystem#196222), both `$ ps -p 1` and `$ sudo stat /proc/1/exe` return `systemd`.  I'm pretty sure I'm using `systemd`.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 Done.

Answer (score 2):

Your network configuration is set in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. It provides that your ethernet interface, eth0, will be brought up automatically on boot and will request an address from the switch or router by DHCP. The fact that your network is working fine, as you say, shows that the file, along with the ifup/down mechanism, is working properly.

Comment: Is this file associated with any unit or service?  If something goes wrong with this process at boot, how do I look for its messages in `journalctl`?

Comment: It turns out `networking` is the name of the service I've been looking for.